# Have any a16z-backed protocols ever been hacked?

Tags: web3-providers, defi, protocol, bridge, hack

This year, we saw the hack by exploit of a Binance bridge and a Ronin bridge due to weak code written by the protocol creators.

a16z Crypto is the most influential DeFi protocol investor in web3, recruiting, training and backing some of the biggest, brightest and innovative minds in DeFi to date.

Have any of a16z's investees ever been hacked by exploit?

Answer (score 5):

[DefiLlama](https://defillama.com/) maintains a database of a large number of [capital raises](https://defillama.com/raises) (including the amount raised and VC investors) and [hackes/exploits](https://defillama.com/hacks). If you merge these two databases by company name and filter by A16z, you should be able to find out.

Update: Two examples I have found are [Fei Protocol](https://www.halborn.com/blog/post/explained-the-fei-protocol-hack-april-2022) and [Compound Finance](https://rekt.news/compound-rekt/).

Comment: could you bring forward your findings to the answer. I don't click links

Comment: I provide an example of a vulnerability that made its way into the production code.
I have also provided two databases managed by DefiLlama that contain a large number of capital raises (including the amount raised and VC investors) and exploits of projects. If you merge these two databases by company name, you should get a more accurate answer.

Comment: then put it in ur answer

Comment: or you know, do it yourself.